# NHibernate cascade update/insert

Tags: nhibernate, insert, cascade

I have a Case class which exposes a Person object as follows:

```
public class Case
{
  public virtual Person Deceased {get;set;}
}
```

I have a PersonalAsset class which also exposes a Person:

```
public class PersonalAsset
{
  public virtual Person Owner {get;set;}
}
```

Assuming I write the following code within an ISession:

```
Case case = new Case();
Person deceased = new Person();
case.Deceased = deceased;
PersonalAsset asset = new PersonalAsset();
asset.Owner = deceased;
session.SaveOrUpdate(case);
```

Is there any mapping configuration which will save the PersonalAsset automatically? Or do I need to call session.Save(asset) as well?

Thanks

David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a reference between them you would need to save things manually.  From a modeling point of view are you maybe missing an aggregate root that owns both of these things?

Comment: I think your response may clarify the problem. I'm not quite sure which the aggregate is - it's either the case itself, or the deceased person.

Comment: I would strongly suspect that a person should contain a collection of assets.

Comment: is right. You aggregate root is Case, and a Person has many Assets.

Comment: You're correct that I needed a collection of assets with cascade enabled.